# Adding 2 lines 2 street address in AD from Batch

Tags: powershell, batch-file, active-directory

I have a batch file that I use to create new users in AD.
For certain offices around the world, I need multiple lines in the Street field of the address.
For certain commands, I have the batch file use powershell.

The line I'm having a problem with is this -

```
if "%office%"=="Doha" powershell -nologo Import-Module ActiveDirectory;Set-Location AD:;Set-ADUser -Identity %locapsname% -StreetAddress 'Tamin Street`r`nWest Bay'
```

While this does populate the street, it literally enters "Tamin Street`r`nWest Bay" into the address.
How can I adjust my code to make it enter on 2 lines rather than a single?

Comment: Try double-quoting ``-StreetAddress "Tamin Street`r`nWest Bay"``. BTW, why use batch to run a command in PowerShell?

Comment: …and use better syntax, ```If /I "%office%" == "Doha" PowerShell -NoLogo "Import-Module ActiveDirectory;Set-Location AD:;Set-ADUser -Identity %locapsname% -StreetAddress \"Tamin Street`r`nWest Bay\""```

Comment: @Theo It's because I know batch more than I know Powershell. Converting my entire batch file to Powershell will take more time than I have at the moment.

Comment: I think you have to backslash-escape double quotes, so they pass on to PowerShell: `-StreetAddress \"Tamin Street\`r\`nWest Bay\"`

Comment: @Compo and @zett42 Using your line still gives the same result as before, "Tamin Street\`r\`nWest Bay" being entered into the street address

Comment: Robert, what I posted was the correct syntax, to do what @Theo had suggested, I just doublequoted the argument to PowerShell, because IMO, that it is how it should be done, _(although myself, I'd have preceded that with `-Command`)_.

Comment: When I add a comment to a description field, I just *shift-enter* onto a new line. It carries over for me into aduc.

Comment: If you are not willing to convert the entire script to Powershell then why did you use it all when Microsoft makes other executables that can update those fields from the cmd line as well.  The DS (Add, Get, Mod, etc...) tools come to mind.